# How do I return a Mono after Flux's onComplete is executed?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

I am trying to save a set of categories. When all categories are saved, set the categories of product to it. Then return Product. So far I've managed to do this.

```
public Mono<Product> save(Product product) {
    final Set<Category> categories = product.getCategories();
    Set<Category> _categorySet = new HashSet<>();
    Mono<Product> _product;
    for (Category category : categories) {
        final Mono<Category> save = categoryService.save(category);
        save.subscribe(_categorySet::add,null,()->{
            product.setCategories(_categorySet);
            repository.save(product);
        });
    }
}
```

How do I return product after it has been saved without relying on `block()`? I cannot seem to find a source to learn these stuffs. Can someone point me to good materials.

Comment: spring webflux is built ontop of the reactor framework, you can read about it here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't block webflux chain manually. try to use this code.

```
public Mono<Product> save(Product product) {

    final Set<Category> categories = product.getCategories();
    return Flux.fromIterable(categories)
            .flatMap(categoryService::save)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .flatMap(categorySet -> { // use `flatMap` if repository.save(product); returns `Mono<Product>`. or else use `map` if repository.save(product); returns `Product`
                product.setCategories(categorySet);
                return repository.save(product);
            });
}
```

Comment: categoryService::save returns Mono<Category> so inside flatMap instead of Set<Category> I am getting Set<Mono<Category>>. Any idea what I should do now?